# Tibbles inside tibbles to lists

Tags: r, list, dplyr, tibble

I have a function that transforms tibbles stored inside lists store inside a tibble. This is because `do` function does that when used.
I then apply a function that filters out certain observations.

However, this function returns a tibble and not a list, so it is stored as a tibble inside the tibble instead of a list.

```
library(dplyr)
data(iris)

# Store observations in a list for this example
iris <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  do(obs = list(.$Sepal.Length))

iris$n <- 1:3

# The function that filters data
filter_fun <- function(x, n){
  if(any(n > 2)){x <- filter(as_tibble(as.data.frame(x)), x > 2)
  } else {x <- x}
  return(x)}

# This makes two lists and a tibble inside a tibble instead of three lists
x <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  do(filtered = filter_fun(x = .$obs, n = .$n))
```

`x` shows three elements in the second column, `<list [1]>`, `<list [1]>` and `<tibble [0 x 1]>` when applied to `iris` data. All of them should be lists. How do I change the tibble inside the tibble to a list that holds a tibble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need a `list`, then wrap the output of `tibble` in a `list` in the function

```
filter_fun <- function(x, n){
     if(any(n > 2)){
         filter(as_tibble(as.data.frame(x)), x > 2 ) %>% list(.)
     } else x
   }
```